# How to get all factors aka divisors of a number of range 10^18 given that I can do this task in upto 10^6 computations?

Tags: algorithm, math, numbers

I am facing problems in getting all factors of a number I have tried this code but this is giving me a certain TLE in competitive programming question.

```
for i in range(1,int(N**0.5)+1):
if N%i==0:
    S.add(i)
    S.add(N//i)
```

I want to use SIEVE to access all factors. i dont want to find just the count but physically access them in in a list ! I wish someone could explain me how to use Sieve Of Erasthosenes in it

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes - with animation

Comment: When 'X' divides 'Y' you can use the results of all factors of 'X' to 'Y' other than re-calculating.

Comment: @zmb I think wiki had helped me enough so that I chose to write a question here :)

Comment: @ManojBanik It will be a great help if you can write a code for it :( because am facing problems with understanding this

Comment: For numbers that large, even with a bitset you still need many many TB of ram though, not to mention the time complexity...

Comment: so there is no approach using sieve to find divisors for that big numbers?@zmb

Comment: Aside from the computational power required, just to give an impression:
1000000000000000000/(8*1024*1024*1024*1024)=113686.


That would be TB of RAM in order to have a sieve for 1 to 10^18.

Have a look [here](http://compoasso.free.fr/primelistweb/page/prime/liste_online_en.php).

Comment: Are you interested about only prime factors? or you need all factors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my computer it works really fast, it will give you all the factors, but it is in Java, if that helps.

```
public class Factoring
{
   private static Set<Long> findFactors(long num)
   {
      Set<Long> nn = new HashSet<>();

      for (long i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(num); i++)
         if (num % i == 0)
         {
            nn.add(i);
            nn.add(num / i);
         }

      return nn;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Set<Long> myTreeSet = new TreeSet<>(findFactors(10050000911364137L));
      System.out.println(myTreeSet);
   }
}
```

Output:

```
[5233, 131627, 14590507, 688804091, 76352123131, 1920504664889]
```

Comment: " TreeSet " allows you to keep all the factors sorted, if you don't need them sorted, you can use Set, that will be little faster than this one.

Comment: You can also cache the sqrt result. `int sqrt = (int)Math.round(Math.sqrt(num));` and `i <= sqrt`

Comment: For a prime (~10^18) this algorithm needs 10^9 operation, which exceeds the 10^6 limitation of the question.

Comment: @vivek_23 I knew Java cache that value during compilation, doesn't it?

Comment: The question didn't ask for "really fast", it asked for solutions that take less than 10**6 steps. This takes more like 10\**9 steps. I have no idea why 10\**6 was given in the problem, but that's what it says.

Answer (score -1):

Unless you need to compute the divisors of lots of numbers over a small range, a sieve is not the way to do it. To find the divisors of a number, factor it, then compute the divisors. Here it is in Python:

```
def divisors(n):
    fs = factors(n)
    divs = [1]
    for f in fs:
        temp = divs[:]
        for d in divs:
            if f * d not in temp:
                temp.append(f*d)
        divs = temp
    return sorted(divs)
```

Comment: Actually according to the question I really want to use divisors for a range of  numbers and then access them :)

Comment: By factors here you mean prime factors?

Comment: Yes, I mean prime factors. You are not going to sieve up to 10**18 in any reasonable time.

Comment: So all the work is done by `factors(n)` which most likely need more than 10^6 operations if `n` is a prime of size ~10^18.

Comment: It will not take 10^6 operations to factor a composite number of size 10**18. That is only true if you limit yourself to trial division, which is very slow. Other factoring algorithms are much quicker.